# iOS SSL TLS session resume via Secure Transport across application launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, tls1.2, secure-transport

I have manager to establish a SSL session with a remote device.

The session is resumable when I disconnect and reconnect to the remote device. The session resumption is done via a function called `SSLSetPeerID`.
However, I have not been able to resume the session when I kill and relaunch the application.

Is it possible to resume a SSL session when application is killed and relaunched ? If so, then how can I resume a SSL session when the application is killed and relaunched?

Comment: Why would you want to resume a TLS session and not esatablish a new session?

Comment: When you resume a TLS session, the amount of data exchanged during the handshake is significantly reduced.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I am also looking for this?

Comment: Session resumption can not be achieved when application is relaunched. Apple's Secure Transport library resumes session only when the application has not been killed. I noticed this behavior based on tests. There is no statement in the documentation that specifies the conditions for resuming a session.